# Stripe with Laravel cashier - Handle recurring payment with trial amount and multiple subscription

Tags: php, laravel-4, stripe-payments

I am using `Laravel 4.2`.

I am working on a project that provides video services to users.

The project requirement is as below :

There will be `two` plans to subscribe:

```
1) Basic - with trial period 1 month, trial amount $1, after trial $10 per month, number of videos 2 (during trail he will also get all the features).

2) Pro - with trial period 1 month, trial amount $1, after trial $20 per month, number of videos 6 (during trail he will also get all the features)

3) Additional - Only Pro subscriber will be able to subscribe this plan too (Pro + additional + additional + additional..), $5 for each additional subscription, will get 5 more videos with each additional subscription.
```

I am using `Stripe` gateway for `payment`. Of course the billing is `recurring` and `Pro rated`.

As `stripe` supports only `free trial` period (NOT `trial amount`), I cannot set `trial amount` while subscribing user to any plan.

As well as an user can have a `Pro` and with this `N` number of `additional` plans.

How can I achieve this? I am using `Laravel Cashier` for the `stripe` operations.

Comment: I don't know for the Cashier part but Stripe allows you to create Invoice Items (https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoiceitem_object) that get added to the upcoming invoice. This means that if you create the customer. the a $1 invoice item, then the subscription with a trial, your trial end up being charged $1 as expected.

Comment: I don't want to charge after 1 month, I want to charge first and then allow the user to subscribe. Cashier in laravel 5.0 and 5.1 supports charge, not laravel 4.2. :(

Comment: @Dev how you achieve this mean trial amount i am facing same suitation